# How do i write an aggregation query with { explain : true } in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is the code not working.

Model.aggregate([{
    "$match": query
}]).explain(true);

Comment: Just the [same as in the shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) `Model.aggregate([{ "$match": query }], { explain(true) });` Please consult the [API documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate) before posting questions. If in doubt, mongoose is built on the core node.js driver. Most methods share the same signature. At least up until the optional mongoose callback argument.

Comment: Ok but i couldnt figure it out and i am new to mongodb.

Comment: It's in the manual. `aggregate([pipeline],{ options })`. All you need to do is look. And of course that should be `{ explain: true }` above. For some reason I copied your error.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `,{ explain: true }` after the aggregation array into a `MyModel.aggregate(array, options)` type of statement didn't work for me in Mongoose 5.2.7 / MongoDB 3.6.6. Luckily, `MyModel.aggregate(array).explain()` is now available and documented https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-explain